# How to apply a class to a portion of text in a paragraph block?

Tags: block-editor

When having text in a paragraph block, how can I add a class to a few of the words in that paragraph, without having to edit the HTML? The existing option to 'highlight' some text is almost what I'd want, except that I want this functionality to apply a class, instead.

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Not without code. With code you can register your own format option in the editor: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/format-api/

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie. That seems like the proper solution. But, though I am familiar with creating plugins and loading javascript with them, I already fail at the first step mentioned here, "JavaScript setup for building and enqueuing", which refers to building something with npm. I do not use, and do not need, npm when creating my plugins. The referenced "format-api" example is also not something I understand what to do with. It's not a plugin.

Comment: "I do not use, and do not need, npm when creating my plugins." You will almost certainly need it if you intend to create plugins that integrate with the block editor: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/getting-started/fundamentals/javascript-in-the-block-editor/

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct way to apply a custom class to a portion of text within a paragraph block without tweaking the HTML. The '**highlight**' feature you mentioned is close, but it doesn't let you specify a custom class.

To add a custom class, you need to edit the HTML and manually add a custom class. If want to try it, here how you can do it.

In your paragraph, select the words or phrase you want to apply the class to. Next, click on the three dots in the block toolbar (it's called the '**More options**' menu) and choose '**Edit as HTML**'.

Now, in the HTML view, you'll see your text. Wrap the words you want to style with a `<span>` tag and add your class. Something like this: `This is your example <span class="your-custom-class">paragraph</span> in to highlight.` Replace `your-custom-class` with whatever class name you've defined in your CSS.

And that’s it! The words you wrapped in the span tag will now have your custom class applied. You can then style this class however you like in your theme’s CSS file.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, this works, but it is not something I can expect less-technical people to be very comfortable with, or to consistently do correctly.